# Lewis structure and chemfig

Tags: chemfig

I would like to use `chemfig` to draw something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\setchemfig{lewis sep=24pt}
            \chemfig{@{x1}\lewis{2:,Sn}(-[:-150]Cl)-[:-30]Cl}
\chemmove{\draw[-]
(x1).. controls +(130:2cm) and +(50:2cm).. (x1);}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there any way to do this better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules=all}

\begin{document}

\setchemfig{lewis sep=0.6ex}

\chemfig{
    (-[2,0.6,,,draw=none]{\orbital[scale=1.2, half, color=gray!50]{p}})
    (
    -[,0,,,draw=none]@{x1}{\lewis[lewis style=red,lewis sep=14pt]{2:,Sn}}
    (-[:-30]{\lewis{0:2:6:,Cl}})
    -[:-150]{\lewis{2:4:6:,Cl}}
    )
}
\chemmove{
        \draw[latex-latex, red]
                ($(x1)+(210:1.6em)$) arc[start angle=210, end angle=330, radius=1.6em]
                node[midway, yshift=-6pt] {\color{blue}\footnotesize \(\approx 120^\circ\)};
}

\end{document}
```

[image]